# How is the Metro Ethernet Forum's "hairpin switching" implemented?

Tags: metro-ethernet

To date, I've found this old document describing implementation of [hairpin switching](https://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/docs2009/new-haddock-MEF-ENNI-support-0509-v1.pdf). In particular, page 13 suggests possible implementations. I would like to know what implementations exist.

A search through MEF standard 26.2 (ENNI and operator service attributes) reveals a description of the abstraction, but not of the implementation.

Similarly, I have no references to implementation of operator virtual connection (OVC) endpoints. I would like to know what these look like.

Thank you for sparing the time to read this.

Comment: Looks like a proposal that hasn't made it...

Comment: Possibly. I don't know what has, though. The abstraction (hairpin switching) exists and is used to transfer traffic between OVCs that have been sub-contracted with another operator.